# Autogenerated properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, properties, field, shortcut

In VB.NET it is possible to do the following in a class.

```
Public Property MyProperty As String
```

At this point a getter and setter is automagically created for you and you can refer to variable defined by the property as such.

```
Me._MyProperty = "BlahBlah"
```

Is there an equivalent mechanism in C# ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public string MyProperty {get; set;}
```

by default they are both public accessors, you can make **one** of them private like this:

```
public string MyProperty {get; private set;}
```

Comment: Aggghhhh, Thank you.... And how does one refer to the local variable itself rather then going through the getter and setter? this._MyProperty = "BlahBlah"; doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I dont think you can specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the property

Comment: you will have to refer as `this.MyProperty = "BlahBlah"` itself

Comment: @MaximGershkovich: re underlying field @Kumar has it right: the underlying field is not accessible by C# code (the generated identifier is not a valid C# identifier). It can be reached with reflection of course.

Comment: @NeilN: the accessibility one of `get` or `set` can be specified to be more restrictive. So having an `internal` `get` would also be allow. (One could have a public set and a private get as well, but that falls into the same confusion as write only fields.)

Answer (score 5):

In C# you cannot refer to the underlying variable of auto implemented properties directly.

Comment: Really? What is the design reason behind this?

Comment: @Maxim: The design reason is probably something like "You didn't declare it, so you don't get access to it."  Just use the default property accessors - there's no performance advantage to accessing the field directly.

Comment: I am more thinking along the lines of how to approach lazy loading properties when you don't have access to the variable itself but I guess its just the same thing.